# present a custom view inside a viewcontroller or alertview - swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uialertview

First of all, I am trying to show a custom UIView or alertview with a pickerview inside my main view controller.

I was able to present the view below using self.presentviewcontroller()
[image: modal view]

How can I show the image above to my main view controller inside an actionsheet controller, I read around the actionsheet will be deprecated soon, is there a way to show it inside an alertview.

I also tried presenting the view by creating an object out of it and adding it using self.view.addSubView().

[image]

The problem with the above image is that, I don't know how to apply auto layout constraints and the buttons aren't functional.

Comment: Try `Display as Popover` at this link http://gracefullycoded.com/display-a-popover-in-swift/. The problem is we cannot remove the `arrow` of the popover.

Comment: @t4nhpt doesn't work either :/